# Convergence. Cauchy and uniform

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

I know that if function is uniformly convergent ($ |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon. \forall n > N(\epsilon)$), it is Cauchy convergent ($ |f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon. \forall n,m > N(\epsilon)$)

So my  question is: if sequence is Cauchy convergent does this imply uniform convergence? I think the answer is no, but can't figure out example.

Comment: Yes because The set of reals is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does; suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a series of functions on a subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N(\epsilon)$ such that
$m, n > N(\epsilon)$ implies that $|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in E$.

Since $f_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence for each particular $x \in E$, we know that our sequence $f_n(x)$ has a pointwise limit; we call it $f(x)$. We must now show that the convergence to $f(x)$ is uniform.

So let $\epsilon > 0$. By our assumption on $\{ f_n \}$ there exists an $N(\epsilon)$ such that $m, n > N(\epsilon)$ implies that $$|f_m(x) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$$ for all $x \in E$. Now comes the interesting step: fix $n$, and take the limit $m \to \infty$ in the above expression. The result is that $$|f(x) - f_n(x)| \leq \epsilon$$ for all $x \in E$ and $n > N(\epsilon)$.
This proves the uniform convergence.

(This last step has to be justified; it relies on the fact that the function $\phi(x) = |x - c|$ is continuous.)

Comment: does this last step use the fact that function is uniformly convergent? Because than we take limit we assume that function $f_m(x)$ converges to $f(x)$

Comment: @JackHavis no, we use the fact that $\text{lim}_{m \to \infty} f_m(x) = f(x)$ for each $x \in E$, that is, pointwise convergence, which I proved above.

Comment: But what if we take a sequence $1/n$ on $X=(0,1)$ which is Cauchy $|1/n-1/m|<2/N<\epsilon, so N=2/\epsilon$,but it is not pointwise convergent, because the limit is 0 and it is not in the domain of analysis, and it is not uniformly convergent

Comment: @JackHavis I think you're confused about the definition of pointwise convergence; I think it is more useful for you to look it up than for me to explain it.

Comment: I actually can't figure out what's wrong. We write $f_k \rightarrow  f \in X$ pointwise if  $ \forall x \in X, \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$. So in my case $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$ it is not in our domain. So convergence is not pointwise. Correct me, please, if I wrong

Comment: @JackHavis your sequence doesn't depend on $x$: you take $f_k(x) = 1/k$. The convergence to zero is uniform on whatever subset of $\mathbb{R}$ you define it. I'm not sure what bothers you about zero not being in $(0,1)$ if you pick this as the subset on which you define the sequence.

Comment: @JackHavis Oh no, the definition is not that the limit is a subset of $X$, it is that the limit in question holds ($f_n(x) \to f(x)$) holds for all $x \in X$

Comment: I don't think that $x$ plays a very important role here because on the set (0,1) we can take function $f_k(x)= x/k$ and all results are the same. My point here is about definition of pointwise convergence. After the limit we say $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) \in X$. So the limit of my function should be in $X$. So I can't say that my example converges uniform in $X=(0,1)$,because 0 is not in $X$

Comment: Okay Thank you so much